# ASP.NET Website no longer functions properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a WebPages (framework)-based site which has been up and running for about 2 years now. Many users have registered and signed into their accounts and reset their passwords.

As of a few weeks ago, they were no longer able to reset their passwords, people can no longer create new accounts and when you sign in to an existing account, and navigate to another page, you're automatically signed out. I have no idea why this is happening.

I've set breakpoints everywhere, I've put try{}catch{} blocks everywhere, but they don't reveal anything at all. Everything seems normal. The code has not changed since release and I've checked the online docs for ASP.NET Web Pages framework and even though there has been an update (WebPages 3.0 I believe), the code is still the same, so I'm completely stumped.

Can anyone think of anything that could be causing this? I even opened a support ticket with the hosting provider who confirmed that the code is okay and should be working. Are there any other ways to debug/diagnose something like this that I'm not aware of?

Comment: You can debug your site with web matrix , did you try that ?

Comment: Multiple ways. I would start by using an http debugger to see what is happening with the forms cookie. Does it reach the browser in a response? It is posted back with a postback?

Comment: Do your Server Clock has Right time. Tried to check the time on Server Clock. Secondly do you got the cookie's value in Request. If you cookie have value and accepted then it should be worked.

Comment: @vittore I have tried debugging with WebMatrix and Visual Studio. Neither of them show anything abnormal.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thanks I'll check the form's cookie and postback.

Comment: @GuptaAnirudhaF1beta thanks, I will check on these.

Comment: Check if there was any update on the server side. Have they update/patched something on their webserver?

Comment: No more room on SQL Server disk or on the IIS machine !!

Comment: @FeliceM that was my first suspicion.

Comment: @Softlion Thanks, I just had this confirmed by them and fortunately that is not the issue.

Comment: I have a partial answer guys. It partially answers the _Why_ of this issue and I will keep this updated.

Comment: Here's some +1 for you all. Thanks so much for all your help. It's helped me narrow down the problem. I now confirm that it's only affecting IE 11 browsers, even though I believe it shouldn't be.

Comment: As pepople can browse so i think problem isnt IIS.people can create new account.But they cant so go i think u should if the connection string is ok and ur website can access ur DB.

Comment: @AsifMahamud Yes the connection string is OK and can access the Database. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I originally noticed this issue with IE 11. So I finally was able to download some browsers (bad internet speeds at the moment) and I tested the site in the latest version of Chrome, Firefox, an old version of Safari and Opera. Everything was working. So I went back to IE 11 and opened up Dev tools after signing into the account and changed the User agent string to IE **10**. I then started the Network Profiler and refreshed the page.

Now here's the difference:

In IE 11 with user agent string as Default (IE 11), I never, ever see any Cookies (I'm specifically looking for `.ASPXAUTH`. Not even after signing in.

In IE 11 emulating as IE **10**, there is always a cookie when signed in to the account. And it's at this time where everything works as it should.

So here's what I've learned so far (thanks everyone for reminding me about the cookies, they were delicious):

Cannot remain signed into account or perform any account-related activities in IE 11.
Can remain signed into account and perform account-related activities in IE 11 with user agent string IE **10**.

So, I believe that I have narrowed it down a little. It is clearly related to IE 11. The reason I did not think to check for this in the beginning was because all of this code is server-side code - not client-side, and I've also since triple checked all of this code and matched it with code from the docs and it's how it should be.

While I haven't solved the issue yet, I now know that it's only affecting IE 11 web browsers. Now, question remains, since it *was* working in IE 10 all the time, and still is, and works in every other browser; Is it my code, or is it really a browser issue?